# html label inserting newline

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to set some text to a label dynamically using jQuery. But i can't get the `<br>` or `\n` to render and give me new lines. It all shows up on the same line and wraps.

here is my code [On JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZaVx8/2/)

My html:

```
<label id="myLabel" />
```

My Javascript:

```
$("#myLabel").text("This is my first line \n This should be my second line.");
```

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`text()` will escape any html code, so instead use `html()`

```
$("#myLabel").html("This is my first line <br /> This should be my second line.");
```

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that `.text()` will ignore your html. You should use `.html()`, soy u can put whatever html you want inside an element. So you'd have:

```
$('#myLabel').html('This is my first line <br/> This should be my second line.');
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

Try this instead:

```
$('#myLabel')
    .html('this is my first line<br/>This should be my second line.');
```